# Symfony2 execute service before controller action

Tags: symfony, controller, action

So we've got SomeBundle and want execute some actions (services\another action from another bundle or something else) before SomeBundleControllerAction will be called. I read that some guys tries it from bundle class, some from event listener (but i can not get in how it works) and now question is.

How to call, proper way, (let it be) service before any of action from our SomeBundle will be called?

Answer (score 0):

I don't like just posting a link, but this pretty much explains what I would do in your case.  You can inject your service into the listener anyway you would like (constructor, setter).

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#before-filters-with-the-kernel-controller-event

Comment: can you show real example for type "controller" (not for exception like in manual) ?

Answer (score 0):

here was a full description of my answer (some bad person put minus =\ but didn't help at all, next time put links if you know where to find an answer) http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event